# Changing the system language programmatically - Android

Tags: android

What I found on this article was interesting about changing the whole system language programmatically.

[How to change android system locale](http://bin-liu.blogspot.com.tr/2012/05/how-to-change-system-locale-calling.html)

It shows 2 ways:

1- Using Class Reflection to access the API:

```
try {
    Class<?> activityManagerNative = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityManagerNative");   
    Object am=activityManagerNative.getMethod("getDefault").invoke(activityManagerNative); 
    Object config=am.getClass().getMethod("getConfiguration").invoke(am); 
    config.getClass().getDeclaredField("locale").set(config, Locale.US); 
    config.getClass().getDeclaredField("userSetLocale").setBoolean(config, true); 

    am.getClass().getMethod("updateConfiguration",android.content.res.Configuration.class).invoke(am,config); 

}catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

2- Using fake class in the build path

```
package android.app;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.RemoteException;

public interface IActivityManager {
        public abstract Configuration getConfiguration () throws RemoteException;
        public abstract void updateConfiguration (Configuration configuration) throws RemoteException;
}
```

And

```
package android.app;

public abstract class ActivityManagerNative implements IActivityManager {

        public static IActivityManager getDefault(){
                return null;
        }   

}
```

The details explained in the article. This works on android pre 4.2. However I tested both ways on android 4.4.2 and it did not work.

My app already must have root permission. therefore the root permission is not a problem for me.

How can we change the system language programmatically?

Comment: Did you mean to type programmatically instead of pragmatically?

Comment: @cricket_007 OMG i used auto correction of google chrome

Comment: I mean, it "works" if you meant "in a sensible way" :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check the new implementation for the new API level and adapt you code to the changes.

you can check the source code here:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityManagerNative.java